# WP How to resume background location-tracking

Tags: windows-phone-8, background-process

I have a question, I implemented the background location-tracking in WP8.
The code just like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662935(v=vs.105).aspx
It work very well, but according to WP policy, if users don't interact with my app over few hours
that my app will be terminated by system until user restart my app.

So, I implemented another background agent task, this task will be auto launched under 30 minutes.
The code just like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx

My question is: Can I do some things in background agent task to resume background location-tracking
? Even if the system terminate background location-tracking, but background agent task will auto restart it again.

Thanks.